# Merge lines in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to merge these code lines?

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(8171) ) {
    wp_redirect('www.abc.com');
    exit;
}

if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(8189) ) {
    wp_redirect('www.abc.com');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can combine the two if statements into one like so:

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && (is_page(8171) || is_page(8189))) {
    wp_redirect('www.abc.com');
    exit;
}
```

The logic is the same, it's just shorter.